# I'm multiplying a numpy matrix column by a float and getting a strange rounding. What is causing this?

Tags: arrays, numpy, floating-point, rounding, numpy-slicing

I trying to update the column of a matrix by multiplying it with a float. See the code below.

```
H = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]])
print(H[:, 0] * 0.1)
H[:, 0] = H[:, 0] * 0.1
print(H[:, 0])
```

Which gives the output:

```
[0.1 0.4]
[0 0]
```

Numpy seems to round the float `0.1` to `0`, but only when assigning the value to the column. What is going on here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`H` has dtype `np.int_`. So when you multiply `H[:, 0] * 0.1`, the output is computed correctly and stored in an array of type `np.float_`. When you assign that float array back to `H`, it is cast to integer using trucation, hence the zero.

You can do any of the following to initialize `H` to a floating point type:

- `H = np.array([[1.0, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]])`
- `H = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]], dtype=np.float_)`

Comment: I just realized that the error didn't occur if I initialized H using floats instead. Thanks to your comment, I understand why! :)

Comment: @ViktorEM. Feel free to select the answer if it answers your question. I've also updated with a couple of options you can use.